# Задача обедающих философов

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, инспекция-кода

недавно начал знакомиться с многопоточным программированием и попалась задачка про обедающих философов:

> Пять безмолвных философов сидят вокруг круглого стола, перед каждым
> философом стоит тарелка спагетти. Вилки лежат на столе между каждой
> парой ближайших философов.
>
> Каждый философ может либо есть, либо размышлять. Приём пищи не
> ограничен количеством оставшихся спагетти — подразумевается
> бесконечный запас. Тем не менее, философ может есть только тогда,
> когда держит две вилки — взятую справа и слева (альтернативная
> формулировка проблемы подразумевает миски с рисом и палочки для еды
> вместо тарелок со спагетти и вилок).
>
> Каждый философ может взять ближайшую вилку (если она доступна) или
> положить — если он уже держит её. Взятие каждой вилки и возвращение её
> на стол являются раздельными действиями, которые должны выполняться
> одно за другим.
>
> Вопрос задачи заключается в том, чтобы разработать модель поведения
> (параллельный алгоритм), при котором ни один из философов не будет
> голодать, то есть будет вечно чередовать приём пищи и размышления.

Алгоритм достаточно простой - на основе иерархии ресурсов,  взят из википедии. Вкратце:

> Пусть ресурсы (вилки) будут пронумерованы от 1 до 5, и каждая рабочая
> единица (философ) всегда берёт сначала вилку с наименьшим номером, а
> потом вилку с наибольшим номером из двух доступных. Далее, философ
> кладёт сначала вилку с бо́льшим номером, потом — с меньшим. Когда он
> закончит использовать вилки, он в первую очередь положит на стол вилку
> с бо́льшим номером, потом — с меньшим, тем самым позволив другому
> философу взять недостающую вилку и приступить к еде.

Ниже код:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import random
forks = 5
philosophers = 5

forks_lock = [threading.Lock() for n in range(forks)]


def philosophers_dinner(right_fork, left_fork, philosopher):
    while True:
        first_fork = min(right_fork, left_fork)
        second_fork = max(right_fork, left_fork)
        forks_lock[first_fork].acquire()
        forks_lock[second_fork].acquire()
        print(f'Философ {philosopher} ест')
        sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        forks_lock[second_fork].release()
        forks_lock[first_fork].release()


for philosopher in range(philosophers):
    right_fork = philosopher
    left_fork = (philosopher+1) % philosophers
    threading.Thread(target=philosophers_dinner, args=(right_fork, left_fork, philosopher)).start()
```

Подскажите, верно ли я решил задачу? Дедлоков вроде нет, филисофы меняются, но не хватает экспертного мнения.

Comment: а в чем задача-то заключается?

Comment: @Эникейщик поправил вопрос

Comment: а что должен делать этот код?

Comment: @Эникейщик, работать))) ну вообще, мне интересно, правильно я решил задачу или нет. У меня самого нет возможности оценить. Сам код запускает 5 потоков (философов), из которых только 2 отрабатывают одновременно из-за ограниченности ресурсов(вилок).